# How to see if an object has a particular method?

Tags: r

I would like to know if a given object has a particular method.
For example, suppose I want to know whether my mystery object has a specific `print` method. From reading `?methods`, I try something like this:

```
has.print <- function (mysteryObject) {
    'print' %in% attr(methods(class=class(mysteryObject)), 'info')$generic
}

m <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris)
class(m) # 'lm'
has.print(m)
```

This is fine if `mysteryObject` has just one class. If it has multiple, there are problems in `methods`. I can get around this by using `class(mysteryObject)[1]`, so that (for example)

```
library(data.table)
class(test) # data.table, data.frame
test <- data.table(iris)
has.print(test) # TRUE since there's a print.data.table
```

However, if I have something with multiple classes but the first does not have a print method, this returns false. Example:

```
mlm <- lm(cbind(Petal.Length, Petal.Width) ~ Species, iris)
class(mlm) # 'mlm', 'lm'. Note there is no print.mlm but there's a print.lm
has.print(mlm) # FALSE
```

This returns `FALSE` as there is no `print.mlm`. However, there *is* a `print.lm`, that is used instead, so I would like this to return `TRUE`.

Speaking as someone who knows very little about S3, S4, etc, **is there a "proper" way to see if an object has a 'print' method on any of its classes?** Ideally this works for both S3 and S4 objects, though I do not know what this means.

I can vectorise my `methods(class=...)` over `class(mysteryObject)`, but I bet there's a more appropriate way to do it...

Comment: Or if I could get the name of the method that is used to `print(mysteryObject)`, that would work too (e.g. `which.print(mlm)` would give `print.lm`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `methods` on every class, `unlist` and search for "print":

```
has.print <- function(object) {
  "print" %in% 
    unlist(
      lapply(
        class(object), 
        function(x) attr(methods(class = x), "info")$generic)
    )
}
```

It is possible to start from the other side (searching for a class in all 
generic `print` functions):

```
has.print <- function(object) {
  any( sprintf("print.%s", class(object)) %in% 
         rownames(attr(methods(generic.function = "print"), "info")))
}
```

To find the method:

```
which.print <- function(object) {
  print_methods <- rownames(attr(methods(generic.function = "print"), "info"))
  print_methods[print_methods %in% sprintf("print.%s", class(object))]
}

# > which.print(mlm)
# [1] "print.lm"
```

#### S4

S4 classes are "printed" with `show` method. If no specialized method exists the `showDefault` is called. Function `showMethods` will show if there is any specialized `show`:

For example:

```
library(Matrix)
showMethods(f = "show", class = "denseMatrix")

#> Function: show (package methods)
#> object="denseMatrix"
```

`showDefault` is also calling `print` for non S4 members.

Comment: Thanks, but I did already mention this in my original question. I know I can vectorise over the classes, I just wondered if something like `hasMethods` or `findMethods` or something like that could be used. Also, not all methods are `<method>.<class>`, I think S4 (??) ones are not listed like that in `methods()` output.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Sorry. Not really an answer you are searching for, but I updated with some info about S4.